# PHP: use mail() with attachment gives .dat file

Tags: php, email

I want to send an attachment from a form over E-Mail without storing the file on my webserver. My script is mostly working but I receive the filename with around 100 Bytes which is not readable. I cannot use mail library.

What am I doing wrong?

sendMailAttachment.php

```
<?php
  $ufile = $_FILES['userfile'];
  $to = "john@example.com";
  $subject = "New message on ". "our website";
  $boundary = md5(time()); // Random boundary
  $headers = implode("\r\n", [
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$boundary.'"'
  ]);
  $mailBody = implode("\r\n", [
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "",
    $msg,
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="'.basename($ufile['name']).'"',
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
    "Content-Disposition: attachment",
    "",
    chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($ufile['name']))),
    "--$boundary--"
  ]);


  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Why can't you use any library? That will make your life so much easier

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ - you are trying to assemble a multipart email yourself, instead of letting an established mailer library do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use any PHP library like PHPMailer. If you want to continue with your approach then you are missing tmp name.

Replace this

```
 chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($ufile['name'])))
```

with

```
 chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($ufile['name']['tmp_name'])))
```